# 16-bit timer in AVR CTC mode

Tags: c++, timer, arduino, avr, arduino-c++

I'm trying to achieve that with an Arduino Uno board ([ATmega328](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATmega328), 16 MHz). So I searched through the Internet and came up with something like this:

```
unsigned long Time=0;

int main (void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  cli();

  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1  = 0;

  OCR1A = 15999; // Compare value

  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12)| (1 << CS10); // Prescaler
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // Enable timer compare interrupt

  sei();

  while(1) {

    Serial.println(TCNT1);
  }

  return 0;
}


ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  Time++;
  Serial.println(Time);
}
```

I'm trying to achieve a frequency of 1 kHz, so I'll be able to create intervals which are a couple of milliseconds long.

That's why I chose the comparison value to be 15999 (so 16000-1) and the prescaler to be equal to 1, so I get (at least what I believe to be the right calculation):

```
Frequency = 16.000.000 MHz/16000 = 1000 Hz = 1 kHz
```

The problem now is that, even though the `Serial.println(TCNT1)` shows me numbers counted up to 16000, back to zero, up to 16000, back to zero,..., `Serial.println(Time)` just counts up to 8, and it just stops counting although TCNT1 is still counting.

I thought about some kind of overflow somewhere, but I could not think about where; the only thing I came up with is that the comparison value might be too big which is -as I think - obviously not the case since `2^16 -1=65.535>15999`.

If I, for instance, make the prescaler, let's say 64, and leave the comparison value, `Time` counts as expected. So I'm wondering: Why does `ISR()` stops getting called at a value of 8, but works when bringing up the prescaler?

Comment: where is `Time` declared?

Comment: This looks like a race-condition to me, you're printing both from the interrupt handler and from the main loop. Imagine how you'd implement Serial.println and what would happen if an IRQ fired and started attempting to print while the main loop was already in the middle of printing a different message. Calling high-level system functions like this from an interrupt handler at all is a major no-no unless you're very certain about what you're doing and the re-entrancy guarantees given by the library, they are not like threads which can be locked out and resumed safely

Comment: @doynax I see what you're trying to say, problem is that it still occurs even though I comment i.e.  Serial.println(TCNT1) out;it still counts Time only up until a value of 8 (same is true if I comment the last Serial.println() out as well and make the output i.e. visible through a  LED)

Comment: @VGD: Curious, then I can't spot the problem straight-off and I fear I don't have a board handy at the moment. Try stripping out everything unrelated from the program, including the serial library, and break into the program with the debugger to inspect registers once the interrupts have stopped firing. Oh, and kick the watchdog from the loop just-in-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the resolution of the timer was too much for my Arduino Uno (16 MHz). Chosing a lower resolution (i.e higher compare value) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: 16000 would only work for Timer1 (which is a 16-bit timer), whereas Timer0 and Timer2 are 8-bit timers. But you ***are*** using Timer1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but depending on the version of Arduino you use, the println call would be blocking. If you call it faster than it can complete in your ISR, the stack will overflow.

If you want higher resolution timing, maybe try differencing the getMicroseconds result in your `Loop()`. You should cycle in `Loop()` far faster than once per millisecond.

If you want to do something once per millisecond, capture a start microseconds, and then subtract it from the current microseconds in a conditional in your `Loop()` function. When you see more than 1000 do the task...